# switch checked check-box with time interval in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, intervals

I'm a total noob at javascript and currently having issues with a project.

I'm trying to make a picture slide with specific transitions. The slide builds on  and  tags for the transition (check-boxes). I tried making a script that changes the checked box after every 5s.

I already got a good chunk of help from a friend but I can't get it to work at all.

This is the script:

```
   var slider_i = 1; 
   function slider_change(){
      if(++slider_i > 4){
         slider_i=1;
      } 
      document.getElementById('select-img-'+slider_i).checked = true;         
      setTimeout(slider_change, 5000);
   } 
   slider_change();
```

Here is the slider I'm talking about: 
http://demo.br-photography.ch/Portal/transitions/index_3.html

I made a jsfiddle, easier to test cause then we can see if the checkboxes without the css properties actually switch. They do, but my slide on the testsite is not switching the images as it should...?

https://jsfiddle.net/t4eapmgb/

Comment: where are the checkboxs?

Comment: What is not working for you?

Comment: The checkboxes are 'invisible'. They are basically stripped down to a rectangle covering the vertical panels, 4 in a horizontal row.

@itzmukeshy7 
I would like the checkboxes to automatically switch around without any actions from the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
   var slider_i = 0;    // !!!
   var slider_change = function (){
      if(++slider_i > 4){
         slider_i=0;
      } 
      document.getElementById('select-img-'+slider_i).checked = true;         
      setTimeout(slider_change, 50000);
   };
   slider_change();
```

**or**

```
   var slider_i = 1;    
   var slider_change = function (){
      if(slider_i++ > 3){ // !!!
         slider_i=1;
      } 
      document.getElementById('select-img-'+slider_i).checked = true;         
      setTimeout(slider_change, 50000);
   };
   slider_change();
```

what's actually happening with your code:

- `slider_i` is set to 1.
- function `slider_change` is called
- it first increments the `slider_i` because of `++slider_i`
- now `slider_i` has the value of `2`
- it now checks against `<4`
- if not true, it checks an element with id select-img-<value of `slider_i`>

The last step generates the id of `select-img-2`.

`select-img-1` will never be reached. I don't know whether this is causing any subsequent errors.

Comment: I tried this, and it works like a charm in jsfiddle without all the css properties: https://jsfiddle.net/t4eapmgb/

Though on my site it still doesn't seem to affect the slide at all... 
http://demo.br-photography.ch/Portal/transitions/index_3.html

Answer (score 0):

For your information, setTimeout(, 50000) is triggerd after 50000 ms = 50sec. 
If you want to wait 5 sec you have to write setTimeout(, 5000)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! That was a little typo. Though set to 5000 ms or even just 1000 ms it is still not taking any action.

Answer (score 0):

Just place script from top to bottom. There is reference error because elements(checkboxes) are not available when initially page is loaded.

Or you may also add try catch block for this issue as follows:

replace this

```
var slider_i = 1; 
function slider_change(){
 if(++slider_i > 4){
   slider_i=1;
 } 
 document.getElementById('select-img-'+slider_i).checked = true;         
 setTimeout(slider_change, 5000);
} 
slider_change();
```

With this one:-

```
var slider_i = 1; 
function slider_change(){
  if(++slider_i > 4){
    slider_i=1;
  } 
  try{
    document.getElementById('select-img-'+slider_i).checked = true;         
  }catch(err){}
  setTimeout(slider_change, 5000);
} 
slider_change();
```

Comment: Wow! That did it! Thank you so much! A detail I absolutely wouldn't have figured out on my own. 

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
//Repeats forever
var variable = setInterval(functionYouWantToCall, 5000);
//Cancel the interval
clearInterval(variable);
```